# Change HTML progress value every second

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the HTML progress value by 1 every second then go back to 0 when it hits 100, but i don't know how to do it

HTML Code:

```html
<progress id="val" value="progressVal" max="100"></progress>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
var progressVal = 0;

function startProgress() {
 progressVal += 1;
 document.getElementByIdd("val").value = progressVal;
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I kinda failed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to execute a function every 100 milliseconds.

In the function, check whether the progress is 100. If it is, reset it to 0. Otherwise, increase it by 1.

```js
var progress = document.getElementById("val");
var a = 0;

function update() {
  a = a == 100 ? 0 : ++a;
  progress.value = a;
}
setInterval(update, 100);
```

```html
<progress id="val" value="progressVal" max="100"></progress>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that :

```html
<progress id="val" value="progressVal" max="100"></progress>

<script>

    var progressVal = 0;
    start_timer()
    function start_timer(){
        setTimeout(addone, 1000);
    }
   function addone(){
        if(progressVal == 100){
            progressVal = 0 ;
        }
        progressVal++;
        document.getElementById("val").value = progressVal;
        start_timer();
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setInterval to call the specific function each second

```js
let progressValue = 0
const intervalRef = setInterval(increaseProgress, 1_000)
const progressHTMLElement = document.querySelector("progress")

function increaseProgress() {
  if (progressValue === 100) {
    clearInterval(intervalRef)
  }

  progressValue += 10
  progressHTMLElement.value = progressValue
}
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```